# Why are residuals correlated with prediction when using linear mixed model with low number of observations per group?

Tags: lme4, mixed-models

I have a database composed of n = 1000 observations of a variable to explain (y), an explanatory variable (x). The observations are grouped according to a variable "group", and I have only 2 observations per "group", while the number of different "groups" is high.

I fitted a linear mixed model (with R lmer function, from package lme4) explaining y as a function of x, using "group" as a random effect.
I then checked if the residuals were normal and independant of the fitted values.
Here I got a problem: the residuals  are normal but are higher when the predicted values are higher. Here, the residual is computed as observed value minus fixed effect minus random effect.

I suspect this is because the number of observations per "group" is low.

To test this hypothesis, I tried to simulated data from a virtual model to test if the same occurs, and it does: when the number of observations per groupis low, I observe this correlation between residuals and fitted values, while I do not oberve that when the number of observations per "group" is higher.

I include this test code below (500 groups, 1000 obs):

```
# generate data 

  nb.group <- 500
  list.group <- as.character(seq(1,nb.group, 1)) # anmes of the different groups
  nb.obs <- 1000
  
  alpha <- 0.3 # fixed effect
  gamma <- 1.5 # sd of random effect
  sigma <- 1 # sd of individual erro
  
  db.RE <- data.frame( # generate value for random effect
    group = list.group,
    A = rnorm(nb.group, 0, gamma)
  )
  
  db <- data.frame(
    x = rgamma(nb.obs, 10, 5), # explicative variable
    group = sample(list.group, size = nb.obs, replace = TRUE), # vector of group
    E = rnorm(nb.obs, 0, sigma) # individual error
  )
  
  db <- merge(db, db.RE, by = "group") # attribute the value of random effect corresponding to each group
  
  db$y <- alpha*db$x + db$A + db$E # y : independant variable


# calibrate with RE
  
  model <- lmer(formula = y ~ x + (1|group), data = db)
  
# diagnosis 
  
  summary(model)
   
  db_pred <- cbind(db, y_pred = predict(model), res = residuals(model)) # get fitted values and residuals

  ggplot(data = db_pred, aes(x = cut(y_pred, breaks = seq(min(y_pred), max(y_pred), length.out = 10)), y = res)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
    ggtitle(paste0("residuals as a function of fitted, nb.group = ", nb.group))
  
  ggplot(data = db_pred, aes(sample = res)) +
    stat_qq() + stat_qq_line() +
    theme_bw() +
    ggtitle(paste0("qq plot of residuals, nb.group = ", nb.group))
```

The corresponding diagnosis graphs are below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCVGx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9AcG.png)

Is this correlation between residuals and fitted values expected when we have few obervations per group, and could you explain to me what it should be the case?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards
Matthieu

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/